# Unable to get major version number of product?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installscript, installscript-msi

I have code to retrieve the Major versions of a product. Declared a property as `PRODVER_MAJOR = 2`
Code is as follows:

```cpp
function myfunction(hMSI)
    string svmajorversion;
    number nsize;
begin
    nsize = 256;
    MsiGetProperty (ISMSI_HANDLE, "PRODVER_MAJOR", svmajorversion, nsize);
    MessageBox ("MajorVersion:" +svmajorversion, INFORMATION);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on the scheduling of the action. If this is called from a deferred custom action, it cannot access most properties directly, and instead must retrieve data through the property `CustomActionData` which in turn must have been set up before calling the action.

In either case, I would recommend replacing the use of `ISMSI_HANDLE` (a generic global handle primarily useful during events) with `hMSI` (the handle specifically passed to this custom action).

Comment: @Micheal Uman If I want to make this work out what are the changes that I need to do in case of deferred custom action? Please update the same code.

Comment: The custom action is in commit execution mode

Answer (score 0):

It might help to actually check the return value of [MsiGetProperty function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Return value ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE 
>    An invalid or inactive handle was
>   supplied.
>
> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
>   An invalid parameter was passed to the
>   function.
>
> ERROR_MORE_DATA
>   The provided buffer was too small to hold the entire
>   value.
>
> ERROR_SUCCESS
>   The function succeeded.